# Does the nice value affect swap?

Tags: swap, nice

If the system doesn't have enough RAM for everything, does the kernel take the `nice` value into account when it decides what to swap out to reduce memory stress?

Comment: If I understand correctly, a process with a high nice value alias low priority is likely to be swapped out when processes with higher priority need RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel does not take into account the nice value for virtual memory consumption.  However, if a process has a low nice value and has not been active for a while then the kernel may take a preference in swapping out the unused pages of this process compared to a busy process that may be consuming more memory.